# please help with a simple Prolog question

Tags: prolog

I have the following Prolog code in my program:

```
conn([oxford_circus, baker_street], 4).
conn([baker_street, kings_cross], 5).
conn([oxford_circus, warren_street], 3).
conn([warren_street, tottenham], 2).
conn([oxford_circus, tottenham], 2).
conn([tottenham, holborn], 1).
conn([holbor, kings_cross], 4).

s(N, M, C) :-
  conn(L, C),
  member(N, L),
  member(M, L).
```

Now I call the s predicate as `s(oxford_circus, M, C).`, but unfortunately it does fail, instead of telling me for example:

```
M = baker_street
C = 4
```

I am sure this is a very simple error, but it seems I can't find it :(
Thanks in advance for any guidance!

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works as you expect in my swi prolog.
Could it be than you need to use a proper command line?
For example the typical problem with swi prolog is not to use -s or -c flag.

Comment: hmm... very strange. After closing and restarting SWI Prolog it does indeed work for me as well. I have restarted the SWI Prolog instance within the SWI Prolog Editor, which did not help. I had to completely restart the SWI Prolog Editor in order to let it work -- maybe the Editor has a bug? Thanks in any case for your help!